# Render ansi to be displayed in HTML

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a program which can render a series of arrays into an ansi textual image:

```
class RenderWorld
  def render_world_for_display(world)
    world.each do |y_axis_rooms|
      y_axis_rooms.each do |x_axis_rooms|
        x_axis_rooms.each do |room|
          print room
        end
      end
      puts
    end
  end
```

This works great when printing to console:

[image]

But when I try to display the characters in the same pattern in HTML, everything messes up.

[image]

Obviously, my function is not changing the text itself, it is merely printing it, so therefore when I print it to HTML it is merely unprocessed array data. I suppose my next step would be to modify my current function to save the result instead of print it. If it is saved it can delivered into the view and displayed.

How can I save text in such a way, whereby when it is displayed in HTML, none of the Ruby datatype fixings are displayed as well?

Answer (score 1):

I got it now. I should of been more confident in myself.

I just needed to create a variable and instead of print, to concatenate to the new variable.

```
class RenderWorld
  def render_world_for_display(world)
    map = ""
    world.each do |y_axis_rooms|
      y_axis_rooms.each do |x_axis_rooms|
        x_axis_rooms.each do |room|
          map += room
        end
      end
      map += "/\n"
    end
    return map
  end
```